# permute columns of Excel document so that first row is ordered alphabetically

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation

I have a big spreadsheet and wanted to do a big transformation. Is there a elegant way to do this?

In a made up example I have columns X,Y, and Z not necessarily in alphabetical order.

[image]

I want to turn this spreadsheet into first row alphabetically ordered,

as in

[image] and preserving the distinct columns

How do I do this without click and drag and copying and pasting the columns? This can get messy if I have 42 columns. Is there some kind of automation or script or trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the screenshot attached.

`Step -1` Select your rows and columns. `Step - 2` Press Sort on Data Tab of Excel. `Step - 3` Press options on the sort dialog box. `Step - 4`Select sort left to right. `Step - 5` Then select the row number for sorting. in your case, you should select row 1.

[image: See the screenshot attached.]